# Getting undefined when trying to get .offset().top value of element in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am running in to an issue with Firefox and Safari where when trying to get the .offset().top value from an element in an iframe, I am getting undefined back when trying to get this value. This seems to work fine in Chrome, Edge and IE, but not in Firefox or Safari.

Here's the URL:

https://twlatl.github.io/styleguide/

When you click the navigation in Firefox, you'll see the error in the console.

`TypeError: this.$iframeContent.find(...).offset(...) is undefined`

The block that is causing problems is here:

```js
gotoAnchor: function($elem) {
  window.location.hash = '!' + $elem.attr('href').replace('#', '');
  this.top = this.$iframeContent.find('h1' + $elem.attr('href')).offset().top;
  this.$iframeContent.find('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: this.top
  }, 800);
},
```

Removing the .offset().top from the element removes the error, but also removes the ability to scroll to that portion of the page.

I've tried wrapping this variable in an .on() method to check that the iframe is fully loaded first, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Your `this.$iframeContent` doesn't have any content in it

Comment: Sure it does. logging that out to console or hitting that object via the console thru cruxStyle.$iframeContent shows the object with the output shown, showing the values from the iframe content that is loaded.

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this (you can restructure to meet your needs)

```
var iframe = document.body.querySelector('.hgt-iframe-wrapper > iframe')
var iframeBody = iframe.contentDocument.body
var sectionHeader = iframeBody.querySelector($elem.attr('href'))

if( sectionHeader ){
    sectionHeader.scrollIntoView()
}
```

> Note: you'll get an error with this ^ because ID's [aren't allowed to start with numbers](https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/). Change the section header ID's to start with a letter and it will work

## Update

Ah, your problem is your are accessing the content of your iframe before its loaded. If you refresh sometimes it loads fast enough and your menu works. You can see in the screenshot below that the iframe was not loaded fast enough and so `this.$iframeContent` is effectively empty (no `<div>`s returned)

[image]

Comment: scrollIntoView isn't supported on Chrome yet, so that's unusable. I've reworked my code to load the iframe src dynamically via JS, and wrap the click event for the nav in an eventListener to make sure the iframe is loaded. Now at least it fails every time when trying to access the .top value on the anchor, but it can't be from the iframe not having been loaded.

Comment: It is [supported in all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=scrollIntoView), just not with the smooth option

Comment: Try stepping through your code with the dev tools console

Comment: The solution was to defer getting the iframe content from the init function and move it to the gotoNav function, where it isn't affected by the race condition. Thanks for the suggestion on scrollIntoView. Using that to handle showing the proper area on page load.